# Pass javascript variable to ruby on rails in js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a .js.erb file and I need to pass a javascript variable to ruby on rails to do a search, how can I pass the value of the variable?

```
var id_control_access = $("#control_access_id").val();
```

to

```
$scope.antennasDataInput = <%= AntennaInstalled.where(control_access_id: "variable javascript", type_antenna_id: 1) %>;
```

Comment: The only way you can get data from the client (javascript) to the server (rails) is by sending it in a request to an endpoint you create.

Comment: Receive the value in the controller through params, assign it to an instance variable.

Comment: The only way to pass data to the server is by performing a HTTP request*. Usually this would be by clicking a link or submitting a form. If you want to send the data without reloading you need to use AJAX to send a asyncronous request. (* well there is websockets as well but that kind of overkill here)